# Как использовать двумерный массив, чтобы отловить индекс элемента

Tags: python, массивы

есть такая задачка: на вход подается последовательность из n чисел(нечетное), ее надо отсортировать и найти наименьшее число, среднее и самое большое, а потом вывести номера этих чисел(от 1 до n), сохраняя иерархию.
Пример:

```
input.txt
5
10.00 8.70 0.01 5.00 3.00
```

```
output.txt
3 4 1
```

Я написала код, рабочий, но он очень долго обрабатывает, думаю как бы модифицировать, но на ум приходит только завести двумерный массив к arr добавить индексы элементов, а потом их отловить как-то, но не понимаю, как это реализовать. Вот код работающий на python:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    n = int(f.readline())
    arr1 = list(map(float, f.read().split()))
    arr=arr1.copy()
    index=[]
    def sort(array,num):
        massiv=[]
        for i in range(n):
            j = i - 1
            key = array[i]
            while j >= 0 and array[j] > key:
                array[j + 1] = array[j]
                j -= 1
            array[j + 1] = key
        massiv.append(arr[0])
        massiv.append(arr[n//2])
        massiv.append(arr[n-1])
        return massiv
    mas=sort(arr, n)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr1[i] == mas[0]:
            index.append(i+1)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr1[i] == mas[1]:
            index.append(i+1)
    for i in range(n):
        if arr1[i] == mas[2]:
            index.append(i+1)
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(" ".join(map(str, index)))
```

Comment: в список можно пихать кортеж (значение, индекс)

Comment: а как это реализовать? вот я считала arr1 из txt, как мне добавить в него индексы?

Comment: примите ответ (с левой стороны галочку поставьте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tup = [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(arr1)]
tup.sort()
print(tup[0][1], tup[len(tup) // 2][1], tup[-1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(arr1.index(min(arr1)) + 1, arr1.index(sorted(arr1)[len(arr1) // 2]) + 1, 
arr1.index(max(arr1)) + 1)
```